# How can I parse a log file to JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a log file (called preprocstats.log) and i would like to know how parse it to a JSON format file using Python 2.6.

The input of the log file is:

```
Preprocessor Profile Statistics (all)
==========================================================
Num            Preprocessor Layer     Checks      Exits  
===            ============ =====     ======      =====  
 1              httpinspect     0          1          1  
 2                   detect     0         33         33   
... (and more rows)
```

And i want to parse it to JSON, for example with this output:

```
{"Num": 1, "Preprocessor": "httpinspect", "Layer": 0, "Checks": 1,   "Exits": 1}
{"Num": 2, "Preprocessor": "detect", "Layer": 0, "Checks": 33, "Exits": 33}
... (and the rest of rows)
```

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: I know, can you send me some doc that help me to do this? Or tell what can i read.. i search lots of things but it doesnt help me..

Comment: Requests to find off-site tutorials and documentation are also off-topic, see [ask].

Comment: What is your input format ? Please add more information on your question.

Comment: I just added more information. Thank you for your interest, i have parsed other files (more easier) to JSON but i dont know how to parse this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution specific to the problem. I considered the 3rd row contains the key values for the result and from the 5th row your values start and it will available up to the end of the file.

**Here is my code :**

```
import json 
a = open('abc.log','r')
text = a.read()
text_as_list = text.split('\n')
keys = text_as_list[2].split()
result = []
for item in text.split('\n')[4:len(text_as_list)]:
    temp_dict = {}  
    for i,j in zip(keys,item.split()):  
        if j.isdigit():         
            temp_dict[i] = int(j)
        else:
            temp_dict[i] = j
    result.append(temp_dict)
print json.dumps(result)
```

**Result :**

```
[{"Layer": 0, "Num": 1, "Preprocessor": "httpinspect", "Exits": 1, "Checks": 1}, 
{"Layer": 0, "Num": 2, "Preprocessor": "detect", "Exits": 33, "Checks": 33}, {}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rahul, this do what i wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to do this. I'd probably use `.splitlines()` method, then iterate through the lines and use `line.split()` which would split its contents at the spaces, at this point you can assign the value as you see fit. If those value can contain spaces in themselves the approach doesn't work that well anymore and sometimes won't produce the expected output. At this point you can either try to experiment with `split(delimiter)` or try using regex. There is no right way to do this but, even though some may be more efficient, I think you  get the idea.